# Epson printer driver needs libqt4-gui

Tags: epson

I'm trying to install a driver for the Epson SX440.  I've downloaded the .deb from:
http://openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-SX440_Series
but it needs lsb installed.  I'm on 10.04, and I go to install lsb 4.0.  But that needs libqt4-gui installed.  I have the rest of libqt4 at 4.7.0, but libqt4-gui apparently changed its name to libqtgui4 at that version.  Since lsb can't find libqt4-gui, it refuses to install, and so I can't install the printer.

What would be the best thing to do here - should I downgrade libqt4 to 4.6.3 (how do I do that?), or is there some way to tell lsb that it can actually find libqt4-gui under the new name of libqtgui4?

Thanks.

```
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d | sed '/\.save/ d'
alex-p-notesalexp-lucid.list
and471-kazam-daily-builds-lucid.list
arx-release-lucid.list
cburgmer-ppa-lucid.list
cheleb-blender-svn-lucid.list
dlynch3-ppa-lucid.list
ferramroberto-linuxfreedomlucid-lucid.list
freetuxtv-freetuxtv-lucid.list
google-talkplugin.list
jonoomph-openshot-edge-lucid.list
kubuntu-ppa-backports-lucid.list
kubuntu-ppa-beta-lucid.list
kubuntu-ppa-ppa-lucid.list
matthaeus123-mrw-gimp-svn-lucid.list
me-davidsansome-clementine-lucid.list
medibuntu.list
mozillateam-firefox-stable-lucid.list
neurodebian.sources.list
norsetto-ppa-lucid.list
openclonkdevteam-release-lucid.list
openoffice-pkgs-ppa-lucid.list
opera.list
pyexiv2-developers-ppa-lucid.list
rkward-devel-rkward-stable-lucid.list
shnatsel-gimp-paint-studio-lucid.list
spideroak.com.sources.list
sunab-kdenlive-release-lucid.list
ubuntu-mozilla-daily-ppa-lucid.list
ubuntu-x-swat-x-updates-lucid.list
uqvislab.list
wfg-0ad-lucid.list

apt-cache policy libqt4-gui libqtgui4
libqt4-gui:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 4:4.6.3-0ubuntu1
Version table:
 4:4.6.3-0ubuntu1 0
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/ppa/ubuntu/ lucid/main Packages
 4:4.6.2-0ubuntu5.3 0
    500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/main Packages
 4:4.6.2-0ubuntu5 0
    500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Packages
libqtgui4:
Installed: 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~lucid1~ppa1
Candidate: 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~lucid1~ppa1
Version table:
*** 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~lucid1~ppa1 0
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 4:4.6.3-0ubuntu1 0
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/ppa/ubuntu/ lucid/main Packages
 4:4.6.2-0ubuntu5.3 0
    500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/main Packages
 4:4.6.2-0ubuntu5 0
    500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Packages
```

Answer (score 0):

`libqt4-gui` is [still available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libqt4-gui) in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. It's a "transitional package", which means it doesn't provide any files, and depends on the newly named packages. It exists primarily to ensure the newly named packages get installed when upgrading. But you should still be able to install it.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudp apt-get install libqt4-gui
```

If that doesn't work, please comment to indicate what happened.

Comment: Yes, I'd tried that, but I get: _Depends: libqtgui4 (=4:4.6.3-0ubuntu1) but 4:4.7.0-0ubuntu2~lucid1~ppa1 is to be installed_.  The name was changed from 4.7.0, and the rest of libqt4 is at 4.7.0 on this machine.  That was why I was wondering if I need to downgrade libqt4.

Comment: @donnek Are you intentionally using a PPA to provide QT?

Comment: Hi Eliah - Indeed, it looks like it has come in from a PPA, but I don't know which one.  Using the script at https://github.com/fab1an/unix-admin-tools/blob/master/dpkg-origins just says "not found in any repository", so I don't know which one to purge. :-(

Comment: @donnek Let's see what PPA's you have configured. Please post the output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Please also post the output of `apt-cache policy libqt4-gui libqtgui4`. You can edit your question and add this to it.